# Why does the Numerical Value 0 in my Source NOT Allow me to Have a Server on a Webpage?

Tags: html, python-3.x, linux, server, beagleboneblack

First...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from flask import Flask, render_template
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM
from time import sleep

class Motors:
    def __init__(self, dir_pin, pwm_pin, pwm_freq):
        self.dir_pin = dir_pin
        self.pwm_pin = pwm_pin
        self.value = 0

        PWM.start(pwm_pin, 0, pwm_freq)
        GPIO.setup(dir_pin, GPIO.OUT)

    def set(self, value):
        if value == self.value:
            return

    assert -100 <= value <= 100

    if (value < 0) != (self.value < 0):
        # changing direction
        PWM.set_duty_cycle(self.pwm_pin, 0)
        GPIO.output(self.dir_pin, value < 0)

    PWM.set_duty_cycle(self.pwm_pin, abs(value))
    self.value = value

motor1 = Motors(dir_pin="P8_18", pwm_pin="P9_16", pwm_freq=1500)
motor2 = Motors(dir_pin="P8_16", pwm_pin="P9_14", pwm_freq=1500)
motor3 = Motors(dir_pin="P8_14", pwm_pin="P8_13", pwm_freq=1500)
motor4 = Motors(dir_pin="P8_26", pwm_pin="P8_19", pwm_freq=1500)

def set_motorOne(v1):
    motor1.set(v1)

def set_motorTwo(v2):
    motor2.set(v2)

def set_motorThree(v3):
    motor3.set(v3)

def set_motorFour(v4):
    motor4.set(v4)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def homepage(title="homepage"):
    return render_template("BootGoOne.html", title=title)

def add_motors_routeOne(state, v1):
    @app.route("/" + state, endpoint=state)
    def handlerOne():
        set_motorOne(v1)
        return homepage(title=state)

add_motors_routeOne('0',   0)
add_motors_routeOne('10', 10)
add_motors_routeOne('20', 20)
add_motors_routeOne('30', 30)
add_motors_routeOne('40', 40)
add_motors_routeOne('50', 50)
add_motors_routeOne('60', 60)
add_motors_routeOne('70', 70)
add_motors_routeOne('80', 80)
add_motors_routeOne('90', 90)
add_motors_routeOne('100', 100)

add_motors_routeOne('-4',   -4)
add_motors_routeOne('-10', -10)
add_motors_routeOne('-20', -20)
add_motors_routeOne('-30', -30)
add_motors_routeOne('-40', -40)
add_motors_routeOne('-50', -50)
add_motors_routeOne('-60', -60)
add_motors_routeOne('-70', -70)
add_motors_routeOne('-80', -80)
add_motors_routeOne('-90', -90)
add_motors_routeOne('-100', -100)

def add_motors_routeTwo(state, v2):
    @app.route("/" + state, endpoint=state)
    def handlerTwo():
        set_motorTwo(v2)
        return homepage(title=state)

add_motors_routeTwo('1',   1)
add_motors_routeTwo('11', 11)
add_motors_routeTwo('21', 21)
add_motors_routeTwo('31', 31)
add_motors_routeTwo('41', 41)
add_motors_routeTwo('51', 51)
add_motors_routeTwo('61', 61)
add_motors_routeTwo('71', 71)
add_motors_routeTwo('81', 81)
add_motors_routeTwo('91', 91)

add_motors_routeTwo('-1',   -1)
add_motors_routeTwo('-11', -11)
add_motors_routeTwo('-21', -21)
add_motors_routeTwo('-31', -31)
add_motors_routeTwo('-41', -41)
add_motors_routeTwo('-51', -51)
add_motors_routeTwo('-61', -61)
add_motors_routeTwo('-71', -71)
add_motors_routeTwo('-81', -81)
add_motors_routeTwo('-91', -91)
```

See where `add_motors_routeOne` has the value 0 and `add_motors_routeTwo` has a value of 1?

Well, the value 1 in that field is there only because I cannot find out exactly why the server denies access to my .py file via a error code 500.

So, I placed the value 1 in the second motor field from above as it is listed.

...

This allows for the server to stop denying my requests. I can stop the motor(s) w/ other values outside of 0 but the line and/or pin in question does not go low.

Therefore, I am stuck w/ a on portion to a Linux SBC (BBBW) that I cannot stop or cancel because of the value 0 not being in its respective place.

Even w/ `add_motors_routeOne` in the negative values, 0 or any other value that is similar, causes an issue with my server running the "button" aspect to control the motors.

...

If you can see an issue that I have overlooked in the source, please provide some sort of evidence or relative info. that can bring this bot back to life with the pin being disabled when called to be disabled.

Comment: Error code 500 means some serverside issue. Normally webserver provides more details into the server log. Please check your web server log, most likely it will contain the exception. If it will be unclear, please add it to the question.

Comment: Hello...the source as it is now just works. But, I am not allowed to have double 0's or double 1's from my add_motors_routeOne and add_motors_routeTwo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPIO.output("Px_xx", GPIO.LOW) did the trick on the motor.

So, I applied the GPIO pins in the source and called them LOW or OFF. This worked. So, now everything works and I lost points. Yea!